# Run a method when button is clicked

Tags: java, methods

I need a certain function to run when a button (reset button) is clicked.
I get an error: " illegal start of expression" and need help with it:

```
private void resetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    String sDay = day.getText();
    String sName = name.getText();
    String sCash = cash.getText();
    String sReason = reason.getText();
    String sCourse = courses.toString();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, WriteException {

    String fileName = "E:\\Java Workspace\\file" + day + ".xls";
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(fileName));
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(name, 0);

    Label label1 = new Label(0, 0, "A label word record");
    sheet.addCell(label1);

    jxl.write.Number number = new jxl.write.Number(0, 1, 3.1459);
    sheet.addCell(number);

    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
}
// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: `resetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {` closing `}` (flower brace) missing. close that before start of `public static void main()` method.

Comment: i cant put it after resetActionPerformet
but when i use any thing in resetActionPerformet { } 
i see this erorr
Error "Unreported exception IOException must be caught or declared to be thrown "

how to declare it in resetActionPerformet ?

Comment: Fix whar @Shashanth suggested, and then post another question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct version of your code:

```
public class FooExample {

    private void resetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

        String sDay = day.getText();
        String sName = name.getText();
        String sCash = cash.getText();
        String sReason = reason.getText();
        String sCourse = courses.toString();

    }  // this bracket was missing in the original code 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, WriteException {

        try {
            String fileName = "E:\\Java Workspace\\file" + day + ".xls";
            WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(fileName));
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(name, 0);

            Label label1 = new Label(0, 0, "A label word record");
            sheet.addCell(label1);

            jxl.write.Number number = new jxl.write.Number(0, 1, 3.1459);
            sheet.addCell(number);

            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();
        } catch(Exception ex){ // the fix
            System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
            //TODO handle Exception as you need
        }
  }
}
```

You should use a `try` `catch` block to handle checked and unchecked Exceptions. I added it to the code. Please note the TODO where you should add exception handling code.

Comment: @Beginner1 why did you unaccept my answer after a long 2 years? Is there any specific reason or it's by mistake?

Comment: I am sorry it was by mistake